# ASP MVC exchange port 80 with another port while client is connected

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The basic idea is when a client connect to my website via `example.com:80`, the controller will check a file name and send it back to the client. But, I want these data sent to the client via port 11311.

Here is a simple explanation of what I am trying to accomplish:

1. Client goes to example.com:80
2. Controller searches a file on the server
3. Controller changes the Response port to 11311 instead of 80
4. Controller sends the file by byes so that the client downloads it

Is this possible?

I am using `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse` to read the file and send it back to the connected client, and I have port 11311 already open in my server.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure IIS to run your application on port 11311, then make your controller send a redirect response to the same URL on that port.